# How can send data from an array in one embed message (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I want to send data from an array in one embed message with few fields but my code sends them as 4 different embed messages with one field

I tried with this Code :

```
    const pListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#03fc41')
                    .setTitle('Connected')
                    .setDescription(Total : ${list.length})
                    .setThumbnail(config.logo)
                    .addFields(
  array.flatMap(user => [
    { name: 'ID', value: user.id, inline: true },
    { name: 'Name', value: user.user_name, inline: true },
    { name: 'Identifier', value: user.identifier, inline: true }
  ])
)

                    )
                    .setTimestamp(new Date())
                    .setFooter('Used by: ' + message.author.tag, ${config.SERVER_LOGO});

                message.channel.send(pListEmbed);
```

But it sends 4 embed messages with just one field that have id,username and identifier, and i don't want it like this. I want it to send one embed message with 4 different fields that have these 4 id,username and identifiers (we don't know how many of them we have)

Array :

```
    [
        {
      id: '46892319372',
      user_name: 'testerOne',
      identifier: '20202'
    }
]
[
    {
      id: '15243879678',
      user_name: 'testerTwo',
      identifier: '20201'
    }
]
[
    {
      id: '02857428679',
      user_name: 'testerThree',
      identifier: '20203'
    }
]
[
    {
      id: '65284759703',
      user_name: 'testerFour',
      identifier: '20204'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. If you want to send one embed for every user containing the ID, name and identifier, then you could do this:

```js
list.forEach(user => {
 const pListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#03fc41')
                    .setTitle('Connected')
                    .setDescription(Total : ${list.length})
                    .setThumbnail(config.logo)
                    .setTimestamp(new Date())
                    .setFooter('Used by: ' + message.author.tag, ${config.SERVER_LOGO});
                    .addFields(
                       {
                          name: "ID"
                          value: user.id,
                          inline: true
                       },
                       {
                          name: "Name"
                          value: user.user_name,
                          inline: true
                       },
                       {
                          name: "Identifier"
                          value: user.identifier,
                          inline: true
                       }
                    )

                message.channel.send(pListEmbed);
})
```

If on the other hand you want to send one embed only and it contains all the IDs, all the names, and all the identifiers, then this is impossible. Embed have character limits and since you don't know how many users you have, there could be thousands, thus busting the limit. And that would block you from sending the embed.

Also your "array" is in fact multiple arrays containing only one element each. I don't know if that's what you intended or not but it's not an array but multiple little ones.

Comment: Yes i want to send one embed only that contains all the IDs, all the names, and all the identifiers in different fields. Actually I know that no more than 10 will happen at the same time and so can i send them as a normal message? If embed has limits. And another thing, can i convert this to a normal array with code and then send it as one message? Thank you

Comment: @TheGloriesVe normal messages also include limits. I think it's 2000 characters each. As for the array, there would be a way to convert it with code but you should just make it a normal array by default with this structure: [{ }, { }]

Comment: i have to get this array with api and i can't just make it normal with the structure. I think if i convert this to a normal array it will send one embed. Can you please show me how can i convert this to a normal array with code? Thank you

Comment: @TheGloriesVe you can create a new empty array, loop through every other single array and push it's content to the newly created one. This should give you a normal array with multiple elements.

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly i have to do. I mean i know what should i do but i don't know how to write a code that push these data to an array. Should I convert this to a string then get id,name,identifier with preg_match? Is there preg_match in javascript? Can you show me a code please? Thank you

Comment: @TheGloriesVe I dont know why your arrays are stored like that. If you collected the data manually, change the code that collects it and instead of making an array each time, make an array once and push to it with the #push method. If you collected the data by hand, simply change it manually?

Comment: @TheGloriesVe I could show you how to put all arrays together in one but that would be another topic and I can't submit code through comments. You could make another question of StackOverflow and get a better answer there.